# Thunderbird and S/MIME Certificates on smartcards

Tags: email, thunderbird, signature

For my personal needs I'm currently using the platform UBUNTU 22.04.04 LTS and GNOME/WAYLAND. Thunderbird is my personal e-mail and productivity client application, now in it's stable version 115.8.1 (64 bits).

For many years I used to sign my personal emails using S/MIME and a high assurance (Qualified) X.509 digital certificate provided on my personal ID card (i.e. a smartcard) by my government (Belgium). It used to work flawlessly under Xubuntu, my favorite OS flavor until about a year ago, with earlier versions of Thunderbird.

Since I migrated last year to UBUNTU's standard flavour (using WAYLAND), it doesn't work any longer.

I experienced the same behaviour with Firefox when Canonical started distributing only the SNAP version of the app. This problem is well known and documented. I applied the recommended solution, which was - and still is - to install the Mozilla binary version along the snap version. I can since happily continue authenticating and connecting securely with my certificates/Id card to any belgian e-government web sites using the Mozilla firefox binary version, while using the snap version for other purposes.

So I tried the same recipe with Thunderbird, ... to no avail. Both versions (Ubuntu-snap and Mozilla-binary) of Thunderbird (same version 115.8.1) display the same, consistent behaviour.
I must precise here that I can load the BELPIC PKCS#11 subsytem and configure Thunderbird like I always did. After asking for my PIN, it can access the smartcard and lets me select the right certificate on the smartcard to associate it with my email account profile. Everything seems to work as usual until there, except that signing a message does not work. It systematically displays the same error message  "... the application does not find the certificate or the certificate has expired". It looks like the message composer (not Thunderbird itself) cannot access the smartcard content. Disabling apparmor leads to the same result, on both versions of Thunderbid (Ubuntu's and Mozilla's).
Still, it works as expected when using low-assurance digital certificates - e.g. issued by CAcert.org - which I also use for receiving encrypted personal messages when needed. But those are low-assurance certificates, stored locally.

What's the point of signing messages using digital certificates with no legal value, especially on a system that is meant to be more secure (snaps, Wayland, apparmor, ...)?
NONE, for sure!

I have started thinking that it's a bug.

Before I file in a bug record, would someone be in a position to provide any useful hint?

Many thanks in advance.
P.